# Cloud Foundry : Set Environment Variables via Manifest.yml

Tags: tomcat, environment-variables, cloud-foundry, jvm-arguments

My question is very simple

Is there any way to set environment variables **via Manifest.yml** **without** running the *vmc command set-env [application name] key = value*  ??

On Amazon it is possible to do the following using the .ebextension files

*option_settings:
   - Namespace: aws: elasticbeanstalk: container: tomcat: JVMOPTIONS

option_name: JVM Options

value: = value-DKEY*

Also I want to set this variable deploying the application from Eclipse without using vmc

MyWar

src

Manifest.yml

Or something similar.

I managed to make it through the set-env vmc command, but it is quite uncomfortable when working with Eclipse pluggin so that when you delete or remove the application variables disappear.

So, it would be ideal to set these variables in manifest.yml .... but I cannot get it or do not give the correct syntax.

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try adding this section to the manifest.yml:

```
env:
  {name}: {value}
```

Comment: I can confirm this works with the latest version of VMC, see this Gist for an example - https://gist.github.com/4654412

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the current code for manifest handling (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vmc-plugins/blob/master/manifests/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin.rb) I guess there is no support for env-vars in manifest.yml.

I suggest you file an issue for it.

Comment: Thank you Ebottard... I'm quite surprissed about that.... Do you know where can i send that issue? Thanks again!

Comment: I guess https://cloudfoundry.atlassian.net is the best place, using the "vmc" component. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many ways with no result.

1. I deploy via Eclipse Pluggin for Cloud Foundry.
2. I have created a manifest.yml file just below the war proyect.
3. VMC version: 0.4.7

The manifest.yml  just constains :

---

applications:

-- name: myapp

env:

```
 my_env_var: hello
```

**No result**, no way (:-

I also have done a gem update ( and find any update of the Eclipse pluggin...)

Updating installed gems

Updating manifests-vmc-plugin

Fetching: manifests-vmc-plugin-0.5.0.gem (100%)

**Successfully installed manifests-vmc-plugin-0.5.0**

Gems updated: manifests-vmc-plugin
Installing ri documentation for manifests-vmc-plugin-0.5.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for manifests-vmc-plugin-0.5.0...

BUT NOTHING......